How to properly build localization string key with a variables inside of it
I have the following code:
Text("key.\(item.count) \(item.actionName)")

And based on item.actionName, I need to provide different translations to implement pluralization correctly. item.count is of type Double (it have step of 0.5) and item.actionName is of type String.
I thought that using different keys in the catalog, like this:
"key.%f actionName1", "key.%f actionName2"

would work. Additionally, the translation would be just "%f actionName" without the .key part, which I used for kind of "namespacing" among other keys.
However, this approach doesn't seem to work as expected. Xcode seems to interpret(I guess?) the string from the Text view as:
"key.%f %@"

rather than "key.%f actionName1". How can I implement this properly?
Also, I'm aware of the ^[\(item.count) actionName"](inflect: true) approach. However, it seems to work mostly with English, so that's not an option for me.
I tried to use String(localized:) but probably wrongly, so...
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

So item.actionName can either be actionName1 or actionName2, and you want it to use the correct localization key for each one. Is that right?

Yes, that is correct. There are few possible values item.actionName can hold. @Sweeper

A hack you could use is to add a new overload of appendInterpolation that appends a string as a literal.
extension LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(literal: String) {
        appendLiteral(literal)
    }
}

Then you can do:
let actionName = "foo"
var body: some View {
    Text("\(1.0, specifier: "%.1f") \(literal: actionName)")
    Text("\(2.0, specifier: "%.1f") \(literal: actionName)")
}

Finally, add keys like this to your string catalog.

Localisation keys will not be automatically generated in the string catalog when you build the project.
See also: Choosing Plural Category Names

Yup this worked... Just for the future readers, pay attention to specifier. %f and %.1f are not the same :) I forgot to change the key in catalog, so at first this didn't work cause of unmatching specifiers.

Is there some way to process string, after localization is done this way? Like, to remove part of it etc? I am trying to remove the number actually. I did try to remove it in translation, and it kinda works, but I have to have count in at least default translation.

@Whirlwind Removing it in the translation should be the way. Generally you shouldn’t manipulate a string after it has been localised, since the translated string is generally not machine-readable but human-readable. If you really want to do this, use String(localized:) and give it a LocalizedStringResource.

@Whirlwind And you will need a similar appendInterpolation overload to the one in my answer, but for String.LocalizationValue.StringInterpolation.

I thought changing it in translation is the way, but it doesn't work if you remove %.1f from default translation (and all others). Ok, I will try this other part what you have suggested!

@Whirlwind Oh I see what you mean. I'm not sure why the string catalog can't do this, since the old stringdict certainly can. And by manually editing the .xcstrings file in a similar way with a text editor, I managed to get it to work like stringdict. It somehow can't be done in Xcode though.

@Whirlwind I think you can post a string catalog version of how to localise plurals without having a number in the translated string (if you don't mind), and I will try and write up an answer tomorrow, describing the "directly editing the .xcstrings file" approach, and an alternative, but rather convoluted way of doing this in Xcode.

Ok thanks! I was thinking to make a separate question. I am just not managing to do it with string catalog and its quite a common use case (where a number is not actually needed).
